# Google Webmaster Tools not showing index pages

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, error

I have submitted sitemap and also fetched pages of my sites but still its showing error like  "domain with protocol `https://www.domain-name` is not available try with `http://www.domain-name.html`".

Previously my old site was using `https:` with `no-www` but now I have redirected to my new site having `https:` with `www`.

Comment: You previously redirected to non-www on HTTPS? And the errors are on www? So the URLs that are being suggested were _never_ valid URLs? Otherwise, this sounds like another recent question: [Google keeps crawling pages that don't exist](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51967/google-keeps-crawling-pages-that-dont-exist/51974)

Comment: yes but how would i get my index data for `https://www.domain-name.com` ? because currently have added my site as `https://www.domain-name.html` in webmaster and its not showing my index status

Comment: Why are you using a `.html` on the domain-name?  Shouldn't that be an extension like `.com`?

Answer (score 1):

To see all of your indexed content in Google Webmaster Tools, you need to register **four** different sites:

- `http://domain-name.com/`
- `http://www.domain-name.com/`
- `https://domain-name.com/`
- `https://www.domain-name.com/`

In other words, all variations with combinations of HTTP and `www`.

Once you have all of these registered in GWT, then you can can see on which Google is actually indexing your content.

Answer (score 0):

You need a new version of your website with HTTPS and `www`. Go to the add to site button and enter your website URL like - `https://www.example.com`.

Once you add your new website you will be able to add the new sitemap and can perform other webmaster tasks.